# How to compare dates lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, if

I currently have the following comparison in a Lightning Component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.opleidingenList}" var="opleiding">
<aura:if  isTrue="{opleiding.Createddate__c >= v.dateTodayMinus30}">

If i print {!opleiding.Createddate__c} i get 2018-07-02
If i print {!v.dateTodayMinus30} i get 2018-06-02
```

I expect a record rendered but my output is empty. How do I compare dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the exclamation mark.

```
 <aura:if  isTrue="{!(opleiding.Createddate__c >= v.dateTodayMinus30)}">
 <!--               ^ missing                                        -->
```